# Convention of notation $(p,q)$ for the metric signature, which number is first?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, conventions

This is a really simple question that I fail to quickly find and answer for.
The [metric signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_signature) for Minkowski space or more general Pseudo-Riemannian manifolds is usually denoted by a list of signs or something similar, for instance the mostly-plus convention would be given with the statement
$$
\eta_{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(-1,+1,+1,+1) 
$$
or simply with a shorthand like "$(-,+,+,+)$".

Now, I know that more generally, the signature of a pseudo-Riemannian metric can be denote by a pair of numbers $(p,q)$, which are two integers that count the respective number of negative and positive eigenvalues of the metric, i.e. the numbers of minus and plus and signs on the diagonal of the metric w.r.t. some locally orthogonal frame.

Now, I am working on something and would like to use this notation, however I can't seem to find anywhere wether $p$ or $q$ is supposed to denote the number negative signs?

I am working with the "mostly plus" convention in general dimension $D=p+q$, so the signature would either be denoted $(1,D-1)$ or $(D-1,1)$, but which one?

Comment: Don't confuse the signature of a Lorentzian metric: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold#Lorentzian_manifold

With the "type" of a tensor, which is often denoted generally as $(p,q)$. The metric tensor for example (in particular the Minkowski metric you mention) is a $(0,2)$ type tensor, meaning it maps $2$ contravariant vectors (and $0$ covariant vectors) to a scalar.

Comment: @Amit I know these things are different, what i am talking about is not the tensor rank.
For example, the Lorentz group of Minkowski space is either SO(1,3) or SO(3,1) depending in the signature (they are isomorphic ofcourse) and the real Clifford algebra of Minkowski space is either $\mathrm{Cl}_{1,3}$ or $\mathrm{Cl}_{3,1}$, again depending on the signature.

Comment: Okay, I think that the number of $+$'s is always the first entry. This here corroborates my assumption I think: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Basic_properties
e.g. $\mathbb{R}^{1,3}$ implies $(+---)$.

Comment: It's just a convention: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_convention - just make sure to state which convention you follow (and follow it religiously).

Comment: I think there's no universal convention, either in math or physics literature. So you have to be explicit... and self-consistent. :)

Comment: To strengthen what @paulgarrett wrote: being explicit is important also because either way the $(p,q)$ notation doesn't tell you *where* the plus and minus signs go :) So if we only write $(3,1)$ someone may assume $(+++-)$ which I literally never saw anywhere in practice (that the time component is the last one...)

Comment: You need to set a convention yourself. However as the integers $p,q$ obey the constraint $p+q=n$ where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold, you only need one number. It is fairly common in the pseudo-Riemannian geometry literature to say that a metric tensor $g$ has *index $s$* if it has $s$ negative and $n-s$ positive principal values.